# Mocking Ext.data.StoreManager method call with jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, jasmine

I have the following line of code inside a function I want to unit test:

```
var myStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup("MyStore");
```

I am trying to mock the store inside my unit test as follows:

```
spyOn(Ext, 'data').and.returnValue({
    StoreManager: {
        lookup: function() {
         return myMockStoreObjectForTestingPurposes;
        }   
    }
});
```

However, for some reason the unit test is trying to use the real objects returned by Ext.data instead of my mock object.

Anyone know why this is happening? Should I be mocking Ext.data.StoreManager in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmine is expecting 'data' to be a function and it's actually an object.

I can see three solutions here, the easiest would be to spy on Ext.data.StoreManager, something like:

```
spyOn(Ext.data.StoreManager, 'lookup').and.callFake(function() {
     return myMockStoreObjectForTestingPurposes;   
});
```

This will actually replace every lookup call with your "fake" function.

The second would be replace the Ext object fully in your test, like:

```
beforeEach(
        module('your-module-name', function ($provide) {
            var mockedExt = {
               data: { 
                  StoreManager: {
                      lookup: function() {
                          return myMockStoreObjectForTestingPurposes;
                      }   
                  }
               }
            };
            $provide.value('Ext', mockedExt);
        })
    );
```

This is replace every inject of `Ext` with mockedExt.

The last solution is almost the same as the one above but you pass that straight to your controller (assuming you're testing a controller), like:

```
beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_) {
            var mockedExt = {
               data: { 
                  StoreManager: {
                      lookup: function() {
                          return myMockStoreObjectForTestingPurposes;
                      }   
                  }
               }
            };
            var myController = _$controller_('MyControllerName', {
                Ext: mockedExt
            });
        })
    );
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try with and.callFake instead of and.returnValue, it should return your mock object then. If i'm right, you can read more on this here:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Best of luck.